# Is the action of G on X necessarily transitive?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

**Note:** The question first proposed here considering $X$ to be the general notion of a topological space and thanks to a respected answer it is resolved for the general case but an answer is still demanding for mentioned condition of $X$ below.

$G$ is a group of homeomorphisms from a compact connected Hausdorff topological space $X$ to itself with uncountable number of elements and we have $|G|= |Aut(X)|$.

**Question:** Is the action of G on X necessarily transitive?

Comment: There are obvious examples where the answer is yes. And for cardinality reasons it is obvious that the answer will not always be yes with some restriction there.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yea it seems you're true , I think the question would be more rigorous if I add the condition that $|G|$ = $2^{|X|}$

Comment: The last sentence sounds senseless... "If $G$ acts on $X$": what does it mean? $G$ already acts on $X$. "for any topological space like $X$ we assume": senseless... Maybe the question is simply "Is the action of $G$ on $X$ necessarily transitive?". Also the title has little sense too.

Comment: If the question is interpreted as in Noah's answer, then take $X$ to be the cone over an infinite discrete set.

Comment: @YCor you're right when you say the sentence seems meanless because making sentences is hard for me in English, I mean the same as you mentioned :"Is the action of G on X necessarily transitive?" I appreciate any edit

Comment: @YCor ,Thanks for your comment, I've just edited the question.

Comment: Answer to your question: no (even if the group of all self-homeomorphisms is transitive), take $X$ to be the torus $\mathbf{R}^2/\mathbf{Z}^2$ and $G$ the group of horizontal translations.

Comment: @YCor Great, it would become interesting if the answer was affirmative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easy counterexample to the strongest version mentioned so far: given a cardinal $\kappa$, consider the "disjoint union" $X$ of a discrete space of size $\kappa$ and an indiscrete space of size $2$. Then $Aut(X)$ has cardinality $2^{\vert X\vert}$ but clearly isn't transitive (it doesn't move anything "between the pieces").

Comment: Yes it's true in this way , I think that sounds foolish that I proposed the problem in such a general notion of all topological spaces.with respect to your answer ,I will edit the question again and ask about connected compact spaces

Comment: You should not edit a question with an accepted answer.